# How can I create sub page for customer like address page in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have added extra customer fields for customer. Now I want to put those extra fields to own page like address is in My account page. How can I do that?

Comment: +1 for same thing i'm hanging and scraping my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to copy the file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/edit.phtml to app/design/frontend/default/default/template/customer/form/edit.phtml then add an input file or else inside it.
Here an example (the code is customized, so adapt to your situation):

```
 <label for="language" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->__('My language') ?></label>
 <div class="input-box">
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $this->getCustomer()->getLanguage(); ?>" id="language" name="language" />
 </div>
```